# Всплытие Function Expression

Tags: javascript

Недавно изучаю JS, подскажите пожалуйста следующее поведение функционального выражения

```
const foo = function() {
    someFoo(); // тут работает
};

someFoo(); // ReferenceError - тут ошибка, что логично

const someFoo = function() {

};
```

Заранее прошу не кидать камнями =)

Comment: Или если можете, скиньте пожалуйста ссылку где об этом можно прочитать

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Когда функция `foo` определяется имя `someFoo` не определено. Неопределённые символы попадают в замыкание. Пока всё.

Когда `foo` будет вызвана, она обратится к символу `someFoo` (а он ещё не определён) и выбросит `ReferenceError`.

Если код между определением `foo` и её вызовом успеет определить имя `someFoo` ошибки не будет.

Вот ещё один пример на ту же тему. Первый вызов `f` ошибается, второй работает:

```
const f = () => v;

try {
    f();
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}

const v = 42;

console.log(f());
```

> ```
> $ node f.js
> ReferenceError: Cannot access 'v' before initialization
>     at f (/home/sv/desk/stackoverflow/temp.js:1:17)
>     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/sv/desk/stackoverflow/temp.js:4:5)
>     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
>     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
>     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
>     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
>     at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
> 42
> ```

**P.S.** И к [function declaration hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function#function_declaration_hoisting) вся эта история отношения не имеет. "Всплытие" функции позволяет вызывать её **до** определения. Функции "всплывают" только если они определены через [function declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function). Не пользуйтесь этим механизмом. Он странный, устаревший и не нужный.

Comment: Спасибо большое ! =)

Comment: "Не пользуйтесь этим механизмом. Он странный, устаревший и не нужный" --- а если мне нужно штук 5 функций определить, то почему нельзя? А как? Через "const foo = function()"? А какая тогда будет разница какой способ?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, используйте стрелочные функции и кое-что ещё. Полный разбор есть тут: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34361380/14775762.

Comment: Ещё и стрелочные. Ответ неверный. Если знаешь как пользоваться и применять, то вполне допустимо использовать function expression. А ваши стрелочные с грохотом провалятся, когда первая функция будет вызывать вторую, а вторая третью и они идут каждая под другой. А такое расположение нужно например для соблюдения чистоты кода и расположения функций по близости контекста (читайте Роберта Мартина чистый код) ... Стрелочные будут выбрасывать ошибку о том что функция объявлена позже использования

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, взаимная рекурсия работает: `const f = n => (n <= 0) ? n : g(n - 1); const g = n => (n <= 0) ? n : f(n - 2); console.log(f(42));`. Порядок объявления не важен (об этом и был вопрос ТС). Функции разрешают неопределённые символы не в момент определения, а в момент вызова.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, хочу уточнить что я предлагал не использовать [function declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function) из-за "всплытия". [function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) лишено этой странности. Есть и другие причины использовать стрелочки, но тут они не упоминались.